# I think my block chance is not working

Tags: torchlight-2

So with my shield equipped and 96 Vitality, the arcane statistics panel states that I have 48% block chance. However I have not experienced any damage being blocked at all. If I'm not wrong there should be an orange word named "Blocked!" when damage is blocked but I don't recall ever seeing such a word on my character when fighting. Is there a bug that is causing me not to block damage?

Comment: Make sure your option for damage display is set to "verbose".  Then let us know if this problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

In summary, details like "Blocked!" are not visible unless you enter the TL2 Options menu and turn damage indicators onto "verbose" mode.